# Zero length filenames in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

In Linux, hidden files are given an "extension" but no filename, such as `.bashrc`. From the Windows command line, the following all work:

- echo Hello world! > .aaa
- copy .aaa .bbb
- ren .bbb .ccc

From Windows Explorer, existing zero-length files can be copied. For example, if the copy of `.aaa` is named automatically as `- Copy.aaa`. Attempting to rename `.aaa` to `.bbb`, however, results in the error `You must type a filename.`

Why are zero-length filenames invalid in Windows Explorer when they are valid objects in the file system itself? Is this a bug in Windows Explorer? If relevant, using Windows 8.1.

For now, I'll create zero-length filenames from the Windows command line.

Comment: Windows Explorer allows you to hide extensions; if a file is only an extension, it will thus be invisible when extensions are hidden.

Comment: Extensions are not hidden. As a side note, its curious that Microsoft hasn't deleted this dumb setting long ago. Why hide extensions?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the extensions _are_ hidden or not; the issue is because they _can_ be hidden. The ability to hide extensions is because of the "need" to make everything user-friendly; if the extensions are hidden, then Grandma can't accidentally make it impossible to open emailed photos with IrfanView because she didn't preserve the '.jpg' when she renamed it from 'PIC1234' to 'Bobby at the Zoo'.

Comment: Interesting perspective. Doesn't that just reinforce the idea that hiding extensions is a poor design choice?

Comment: That depends. If you take the position that one should not use a computer without understanding what's going on inside, then yes, it's a poor design choice. That's likely why most power users turn that setting off, and expose the extensions, complete with risk factors. But if you take the position that a computer can and should be an appliance, then hiding the extensions is a way of protecting the (non-knowledgeable) user from doing things that May Cause Problems.

Comment: FWIW, I'm a power user, or even 'deeper'. OTOH, many of the people I support in my job shouldn't even be allowed to have access to the File Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an official Microsoft statement whether this is a bug or intended behavior.

There's, however, a trick to use such name without getting the *"You must type a filename"* error: name the file `.bbb.` (extra dot at the end), Windows Explorer will happily autocorrect it to `.bbb`!

Comment: Oh wow, that works! First you get the warning `If you change a filename extension, the file might become unusable. Are you sure you want to change it?`. Thereafter Explorer auto-corrects to the desired name. Both weird and awesome! Nice trick, thanks.